# setValue(value, forKey) somehow changes the whole array in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I try to change the value in the object I created. But somehow after this easy operation the whole array is editing.

This is `Swift 4.2`, I'm using `Realm` and iOS 12.4.

```swift
let index = indexes[i].map { String($0) }.joined(separator: "")
//index is "00"

let obj = object[index] 
print(object)

let key = (o.value)["values"].array![Int(key.0)!]
obj?.setValue(res, forKey: key["prop_name"].string!) //example data provided in screenshot

print("Adding property " + (key["prop_name"].string! ) + " with value '" + (key["value"].string!) + "' = " + res) //in example I add property 'number' with value = 1
print(object)
```

I expect one `Object` to change.

[image: Swift's prints]

Comment: You sure you have an array of distinct objects?

Comment: @DaveNewton, they are here at different indexes. One has to be with `'number' = 1`  and the other with the `'number' = 0`

Comment: Is this a question or a statement? What is 'o.value'? What does the Realm object look like as it appears you've got two objects but are referring to it as one object. Can you clarify what you're trying to do as it's very confusing as it is without more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poor me.

`Realm` links `Object` you created before with an array.

So I needed to create different objects and put them in this array. I edited the same `Object` every time.

Comment: Is this an answer or additional information as it's very unclear.